# Send data via Up Navigation for Android

Tags: android, android-intent, navigation

I am switching between activities (1 and 2) via Up Navigation:

- Activity 1 delivers data via Intent.putExtra to activity 2.
- In activity 2 this data has to be delivered back to activity 1 when using its Up Navigation.

How do I have to code this?

Comment: Thank you!
The hint startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode) lead me to the right answers and How-tos.

Answer (score 0):

You should start activity 2 with `startActivityForResult`, that way it can send back data to the starter activity.

For more info check out [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) tutorial on the Android developer site.

Answer (score 0):

You have to start Activity2 with `startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode)` method.

On Activity2 you have to set the data you want to return with the `setResult(int resultCode, Intent data)` method

On Activity1 you have to implement the `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)` method. This is where you get the data from Activity2

Look the Activity doc for more information [enter link description here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)